# Passing a Func<T, TResult> where TResult is unknown

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Note: Please re-tag and/or re-name appropriately

---

I have a class, `FooEnumerator`, that wraps a `Foo` and implements `IEnumerable<FooEnumerator>`. The `Foo`s represent a tree-like data structure, the `FooEnumerator`s that are enumerated are the child nodes of the current node.

`Foo` is a vendor supplied data object. `FooEnumerator` implements a bunch of custom filtering code.

```
class FooEnumerator : IEnumerable<FooEnumerator>
{
    public Foo WrappedNode { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get { return WrappedNode.Name; } }
    public int Id { get{ return WrappedNode.Id; } }
    public DateTime Created { get{ return WrappedNode.Created; } }

    public FooEnumerator(Foo wrappedNode)
    {
        WrappedNode = wrappedNode;
    }

    public IEnumerator<FooEnumerator> GetEnumerator()
    {
          foreach (Foo child in this.GetChildren())
              if(FilteringLogicInHere(child))
                    yield return new FooEnumerator(child);
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to be able to sort each level of the tree with a given (arbitrary) expression, defined when the top level `FooEnumerator` is created, and have this expression passed down to each newly enumerated item to use.

I'd like to define the sort expression using lambda's, in the same way you would with the OrderBy function. In fact, it is my intention to pass the lambda to `OrderBy`.

The signiture for OrderBy is

```
OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

where `TKey` is the return type of the given `Func`, but is a Type Parameter in the method signature and is figured out at compile time.

Example usage

```
var x = GetStartingNode();

var sort = n => n.DateTime;
var enu = new FooEnumerator(x, sort);

var sort2 = n => n.Name;
var enu2 = new FooEnumerator(x, sort2);
```

The sort expression would then be stored in a class variable and `FooEnumerator` would work like:

```
// pseudo-implementation

private Expression<Func<Foo, TKey>> _sortBy;

public FooEnumerator(Foo wrappedNode, Expression<Func<Foo, TKey>> sortBy)
{
    WrappedNode = wrappedNode;
    _sortBy = sortBy;
}

public IEnumerator<FooEnumerator> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (Foo child in this.GetChildren().OrderBy(_sortBy))
        if(FilteringLogicInHere(child))
            yield return new FooEnumerator(child);
}
```

**How can I specify the type of TKey (implicitly or explicitly) in this use case?**

I don't want to hard code it as I want to be able to sort on any and all properties of the underlying `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't create a member delegate variable of type `Expression<Func<Foo,TKey>>` since `TKey` is never specified. However, you could create a member of type `Expression<Func<Foo,IComparable>>` which may suffice for your purposes. You could need to change your `FooEnumerator` constructor to accept this signature as well, of course.

**EDIT:** Others have suggested parameterizing your `FooEnumerator` so that it accepts a `TKey`. You can certainly do this, but you should be aware of the issues that emerge:

1. **By parameterizing the enumerator you are then kicking the bucket down the road.** Any code that wants to store a `FooEnumerator<T>` has to have a-priori knowledge of the type `T`. You could, however, implement a non-generic interface `IFooEnumerator` to deal with that.
2. **Parameterizing an enumerator creates issues if you want to support ordering on multiple fields in the future.** C# doesn't support generics with a variable number of type parameters, which limits the creation of generics that require multiple arbitrary types. This issue is harder to deal with, since it's awkward to start creating `FooEnumerator<T>`, `FooEnumerator<T1,T2>`, `FooEnumerator<T1,T2,T3...>`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can also parameterize your Enumerator:

```
class FooEnumerator<TKey> {

  // ... All your 'pseudo' code would work here

}
```

I recommend programming against the interface using `IComparable` however.